# DAX Round up and then Sum a calculated column grouped by a column

Tags: dax

Using powerbi/DAX, I need to create a measure to sum the numbers in a calculated column ('Units'), grouped by 'Order' and then round up to the next integer.

I tried (without rounding yet):
OrderSummary = SUMMARIZE(tblOrder, tblOrder[OrderNumber], "TUnits", SUM(tblOrder[Units]))

I get error 'The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.'

```
Order   | Units   
---------------
 OrderA | 1.1     
 OrderA | 2.3     
 OrderB | 2.4     
 OrderB | 4.5
```

The total for OrderA should be 2.3 + 1.1, so 3.4 rounded up to 4
The total for OrderB should be 2.4 + 4.5, so 6.9 rounded up to 7

The output for the DAX measure should be 11

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried and show a sample of output to highlight where you're having issues? I'm sure you've tried [`ROUNDUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/roundup-function-dax), so where are you hitting issues?

Comment: I added what I tried. I don't think SUMMARIZE works as a measure. It does not work as shown as a calculated colum either.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to use a table instead of a column for the SUMMARIZE. 
Steps:

Create new table

```
OrderSummary = SUMMARIZE(tblOrder, tblOrder[OrderNumber], "TUnits", SUM(tblOrder[Units]))
```

Create new colum (for rounding)

```
Round = ROUNDUP(OrderSummary[TUnits], 0 )
```

Comment: Never use summarize function to add a new column making aggregate operation. Summarize is good for grouping, and ADDCOLUMNS() is good for adding new column. Do not forget to add calculate to make context transition.